# Unable to get XML response using @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having small sample example where i am using @RestController  as we know that @RestController is combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody . 
In below code snippet i can get the response in json format but **if I want  response in XML what should I try?**

```
     @RestController
     public class CreditCardController {

     @Autowired
     CreditCradService creditcardService;

     @RequestMapping(path = "/getAllCards")
     public List<CreditCard> credit() {
         return creditcardService.getAllCards();
    }
}
```

I tried couple of things which did not work:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/getAllCards", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully return XML payload, you need the following dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Next, you have to annotate your Java class you want to return from your controller with `@XmlRootElement`, e.g.:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CreditCard {
   // your data class
}
```

and then you can finally specify the `produces` attribute of your `@GetMapping` like you are already doing it:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getAllCards", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public List<CreditCard> credit(){
  return creditcartService.getAllCards();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rieckpil ,   Thanks for your valuable time . Your suggestion works perfectly . Thanks a lot  :)

Comment: you are welcome, can you accept the answer as correct, so developers in the future will easily recognize it?